# Bad configuration option (SSH)

Tags: github, ssh

```
macbookair@Furqans-MacBook-2021 ~ % ssh -T username@github.com 
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/100-macos.conf: line 2: Bad configuration option: usepam
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/100-macos.conf: line 3: Bad configuration option: acceptenv
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/100-macos.conf: line 4: Bad configuration option: subsystem
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/100-macos.conf: terminating, 3 bad configuration options
macbookair@Furqans-MacBook-2021 ~ % sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

When ever i try "ssh -T furqanistic@github.com " OR "ssh root@" OR push my branch it shows me this error

Comment: Looks like you have bad configuration options. Similar post here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1698879/cannot-establish-ssh-connection-on-mac-terminal-4-bad-configuration-options

Comment: @James_B This may look similar but there is another issue, files are different ... is there any way to reset my whole ssh folder ? i can't find any good way... i think i messed up a lot

Comment: The sshd_config files are for the sshd server program, not the ssh client program. Somehow you've configured ssh to read the wrong set of configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i got the solution,I completely messed up the ssh_config and sshd_config files...
Man pages for [sshd_config](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) (the server-side config, which includes the AcceptEnv, AuthorizedKeysFile, Subsystem, and UsePAM keywords) vs [ssh_config](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) (the client-side config, which doesn't have any of those -- although it does have some related ones, like SendEnv, SetEnv, and SessionType ).

I took the latest files of ssh_config and sshd_config from github and also updated the config file by entering...

```
sudo nano ~/.ssh/config
```

and updated my host [settings](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/https://)

Answer (score 0):

> This may look similar but there is another issue, files are different ... is there any way to reset my whole ssh folder ?

First, as [explained here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331876/persistently-disable-password-authentication-in-sshd-on-macos), you can add any setting you need for `sshd_config` to a file in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf`.

The [file `100-macos.conf`](https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2021/10/27/macssh/) comes with [MacOS Monterey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey).

Editing that file would likely get reverted upon the next patch, so it is best to leave it alone, and add a new conf file if you need custom settings.

Check if [Time Machine is activated](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) to restore the original content of `100-macos.conf` (unless you can upgrade your OS, which would reset its content)